# Multiple AJAX calls making IE complain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

So we have this Javascript function:

```
function GenerateTermSheet()
        {
            var urlString = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/RenderPartialTermSheetView")%>";
            $('#termSheetPopup input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
                var checkedName = $(this).attr("name");
                var json = 
                {
                    id : GetGUIDValue(),
                    viewName : checkedName
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: urlString,
                    async: false,
                    data: json,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#termSheetPrinted').append(data + '<br>');
                    }
                });
            })
            $('#termSheetPopup').dialog('close');
            $('#termSheetPrinted').dialog('open');
            $("#termSheetPrinted").jqprint();
        }
```

When we call this function and it has to loop through a lot of items, IE decides to complain and cut the Javascript process. We've never had an issue with this in Firefox however, so I know it's only IE (8 specifically).

Do you guys know of any way I can get this to work in IE no matter how many calls it needs to make?

Note: I know sync AJAX is retarded, but we needed it for this specific case so the calls were completed in order, rather then some of the AJAX calls actually made later, completing before ones called earlier.

Edit: Error coming back from IE -->

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 16 Mar 2011 19:37:48 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 290
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: https://extranetint.chathamfinancial.com/mvc/Indications.cfc/results/1373c0e6-2696-4b7a-a911-11a71efcf83b
```

Comment: Not the reason for your problems, but you're missing a semicolon on the fifth line from the bottom.

Comment: Way does it have to make multiple calls? Could you not do one call and return the data back as a JSON object where by they can utilise it again at a later stage.

Comment: Can you post the error message from the IE?

Comment: I actually cannot retrieve the error message from IE at the moment. It only happens some of the time and with my luck right now it decided it's going to work. It looks like it only happens when it feels really bogged down.

Comment: @Alistair - we are looking into this refactoring but right now (two days away from release), we just don't have time =/ The life of a developer right?

Comment: Can we see the calling function that calls this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your async problem this maybe of some use http://vimeo.com/12529436 Paul Irish : 10 Things I Learned from the jQuery Source. If you go through it he mentions a method that you can use it you have to run multiple ajax calls in a specific order.

Comment: judging my OriginalSyn answer you will need to use this technique. Fast forward to 07:40 and last about 5mins. Intead of using setInterval you can use setTimeout and call itself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too many concurrent requests. IE6/7 can handle 2, IE8 can handle up to 6 unless your on dialup, then 2.

Comment: But are AJAX requests concurrent if they are synchronous? And if so, what would the fix be?

Comment: Also, IE seems to breaking on anything over 12 iterations at the moment, but 12 and under work fine.

Comment: Oh I missed that... http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7391 this might be related. Sorry but this does not look good for you.

Comment: @OrigalSyn very interesting I did not know about how many requests IE can handle.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error shows up when the code is messed up, I think it´s not a matter of a timeout in the ajax call or something like that.

Check out the definition of the first variable, maybe the fact you have "xxx" inside another couple of quoting marks. Use something like

```
 var urlString = '<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/RenderPartialTermSheetView")%>';
```

And check if that works. Check also if something else should be escaped in the variable content. Maybe a simple thing could actually do the trick. Otherwise, the checks on the ajax call shoud be performed as other people said.